# Find text of anchor tag

Tags: jquery

Trying to find anchor text:

```
      var builduri = $('#dbtables li a href', this).text().toLowerCase(); 
      var pageUri = "http://www." + builduri + ".php" 
      alert(pageUri);
```

The above returns empty var for builduri, this is what I get in alert box.

http://www..php

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

To get the `href` value:

```
var a_href = $('#dbtables li a').attr('href');
```

#### Edit

To get the text value:

```
var a_text = $('#dbtables li a').text()
```

Comment: looking for text string in anchor link not the href

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to go as far as `href`.

All you need is: `var builduri = $('#dbtables li a', this...`

`href` is an attribute of the `a` tag, not an element.

**However**

It looks like you want a url... so maybe you DO want the href, in which case you need to do this:

Instead of `var builduri = $('#dbtables li a', this).text()` you want `var builduri = $('#dbtables li a', this).attr('href')`

Comment: looking for text string in anchor link not the href

Comment: then use the first part... just get rid of the `href` bit in your element selector.

Answer (score 0):

The particular selector syntax you are using here is only valid for elements yet `href` is an attribute.  You need to instead select the anchor element and query that result for it's attribute `href`

```
var builduri = $('#dbtables li a', this).attr('href').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: looking for text string in anchor link not the href

Comment: @ussteele in that case use `.text` instead of `.attr`